# Java executors: How to notify a single waiting thread within the executer?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify, executor

So here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

I have a FixedThreadPool with 5 Threads in it. Those threads just sit there and wait to be notified.
When notified, the thread within the pool starts to do stuff.

Now, whenever some triggering event occurs, one and only one **waiting** thread within the pool must be notified.
Is it possible to accomplish this at all?

Here is what I tried, but i get an IllegalMonitorStateException:

```
public class Server {
    private class WorkerThread implements Runnable{ 
        private Object lock = null;

        WorkerThread(Object lock){
            this.lock = lock;
        }

        public void run() {
            try{
                do{
                    synchronized(lock){
                        wait();
                    }
                    // doSomeThing
                }while(true);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    private ExecutorService executor = null;
    private Object lock = new Object();

    Server() {
        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
            executor.execute(new WorkerThread(lock));
        }
    }

    public void calledWhenTriggerEventOccurs(){
        synchronized(lock) {executor.notify();}
    }
}
```

Comment: submit one task to the pool, and one thread from the pool will execute it. I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Implement your own thread pool. In general, it is however the idea of a thread pool to offer a row of exchangeable threads without a certain requirement to run a task by a specific thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.notifyAll` notifies all threads waiting on this Object's monitor. `Object.notify` notifies one (random) thread waiting on the monitor. 
Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I tried that before, but I get an IllegalMonitorStateException. I added some code to my initial posting.

Comment: @JosephMüller: to call notify() on `executor`, you need to hold the lock of `executor`. To call wait() on an object (your thread each call wait() on `this`), you need to hold the lock o this object (i.e. `this`). If you want to notify a thread waiting on an object o, you must call notify on this object o. wait() and notify() are very low-level mechanisms, hard to use correctly. And you don't seem to understand them. Use higher-level abstraction from the java.util.concurrent package.

Comment: @JosephMüller Just remove the declaration of `lock` from `WorkerThread` and replace `wait()` and `executor.notify()` in your code with `lock.wait()` and `lock.notify()` respectively. The rule is that you `wait` and `notify` on the same object, and it has to happen within a `synchronized` block on that same object.

Comment: Removed that lock object and passed executor to the WorkerThread. I still get an IllegalMonitorStateException.

Comment: OK, I've got it now. Thanks guys.